# Get turn_count from Watson Assistant

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-assistant

I am using Watson Assistant to send sms to clients. I am able to get the message text and other info from watson in my api. I need to get the sequence number of the messages between the user and the AI. So the first message will start with sequence number 1 and the user reponse will be 2 and so on...
I was reading the Watson documentation and I found [this:](https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=node#message)

> ***turn_count A counter that is automatically incremented with each turn of the conversation. A value of 1 indicates that this is the the
> first turn of a new conversation, which can affect the behavior of
> some skills (for example, triggering the start node of a dialog).***

I tried this:

```
this.assistant?.messageStateless({assistantId: this.assistantId as string }).then(res => {
      if(res.result.context.global?.system?.turn_count != undefined) {
         console.log(turnCount = res.result.context.global?.system?.turn_count);
      }      
    });
```

This code always returns 1. How do I get that number from Watson?

Comment: Do you send the context back to Watson Assistant or always start a new session? The context includes a unique session ID.

Comment: You should use the stateful api if u r relying on Watson to get the turn count also use `return_context` option to get the fontext back